# Como centralizar uma lista juto com os bullets?

Tags: html, css, html5

Estou mexendo com css e estou com um problema com um problema que estou a alguns dias tentando resolver, tentei dos melhores métodos, mas nenhum resolveu.

**O problema é:**
Estou tentando centralizar a lista junto com os bullets (as bolinhas que fica na esquerda), quando você faz uma linha não é problema, mas quando ocorre uma quebra de linha natural (sem utilizar tags como `<p>` e `<br>`), ele deixa de ficar ao lado das bullets.

Eu tentei também fazer os bullets com `<span>` ou `<i>`, mas o problema não está nos bullets mas sim no espaço que o `<li>` está ocupando.

**Códigos:**

```css
.text-space{
 display: flex;

  width: 500px;

  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
}

.text-space>ul{

text-align: center;

}

.text-space>ul>li{

 margin-top: 10px;

}

**Referência e código**
```

```html
<div class="text-space">

  <ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
   <li> Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt </li>
   <li>Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </li>
   <li>Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. </li>
  </ul>

 </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta adicionar `list-style-position: inside;` à div que tem os bullets.

```css
.text-space{
 display: flex;

  width: 500px;

  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
}

.text-space>ul{

text-align: center;

}

.text-space>ul>li{

 margin-top: 10px;

}

**Referência e código**
```

```html
<div class="text-space" style="list-style-position: inside;">

  <ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
   <li> Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt </li>
   <li>Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </li>
   <li>Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. </li>
  </ul>

 </div>
```

Comment: Você me ajudou bastante, e esse nem foi meu erro, mas isso solucionou, meu problema foi na hora de montar a lista, estava utilizando o código assim:

```<ul> <li> <p> TXT </p> </li> <ul> ```

 Isso fazia com que a bullet iria parar em cima do texto.

Muito obrigado.

Comment: @WEBLastWolf mas não era isto que pretendias centrar os pontos?

Comment: Sim, você me ajudou a encontrar meu erro, quando eu utilizei o ```list-style-position: inside;``` os bullets acabavam parando em cima do texo, mas o problema é que no meu outro código eu estava utilizando a tag ```<p>```

Comment: Ok, eu usei com o código que forneceste por isso não identifiquei esse problema. Se quiser em vez de apagar os ```<p>``` pode simplesmente trocar por ```<span>```.

Comment: A tag ```<span>``` tem que tomar muito cuidado quando usar ela, isso faz com que o deficiente visual se perca pelo site, muitos programas que descrevem ignoram o ```<span>```